# Magento 2.3.3: Does catalog_product_view.xml not pass down containers to specific product types?

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, magento2.3.3, page-layouts

I have created a catalog_product_view.xml in my theme and when I go to create a widget and select all product types in the layout updates section I can see my custom container I created.

If I then change to simple product type I can't see my container. Do I really need to configure each product type individually?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <!-- Custom Containers -->
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
                <container name="test.container" label="Test Container" after="product.name" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="test-container" />
            </referenceContainer>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Can you update the code which you have written on your catalog_product_view.xml

Comment: Yeah, I just done it and it updated fine. However, it is still not showing on specific product types. Just on all product types.

Comment: Can you add your code to the question what you have done?

Comment: @SukumarGorai I have added the code.. pretty basic so I'm not sure as to why it isn't working.

Comment: It should show. Can you take screenshot by Inspect Element for all product types and send it here in comments or to your question?

Comment: Apparently not, every time I move my mouse off the screen the drop-down closes.

Comment: As I expected the catalog_product_view.xml affects all product types.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/product-layouts.html#product-view-page

Why mine isn't working then in that case I have no idea.

Comment: I have just done a fresh install. Same issue.. the only file I have changed is this one with the code above. I tried searching on GitHub for issues but doesn't look like there is one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with core Magento. I have created an issue on the [official GitHub repository](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26343).